# Script taking too long to delete empty folders

Tags: powershell

I am running a PowerShell Script on a shared windows 2008 R2 server via a remote computer. The script is supposed to delete empty folders older than 45 days. But it's taking too long to delete even the first folder.

However - I would concede that the folder tree is quite complicated and has as many as 17k folders in total with 60k+ files in them with several complicated branchings.

I ran this about 17 hours ago and still have failed to see a single folder getting deleted.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Delete_APAC -Force -Exclude $Keep_this_folder , $Keep_this_folder2 , $Keep_this_folder3 , $Keep_this_folder4 -Recurse|Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.Fullname -Force -Recurse).Count -eq 0 -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $regional_limit -or $_.CreationTime -lt $regional_limit)}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

My guess is that the script is first taking a list of all the empty folders, because as I mapped to the shared drive from the remote comp and ran the script without the remove item bit and it still was taking time. However, when I removed the second pipeline too- it started listing the folders right away. Although, there is an empty folder older than 45 days in the drive right in the beginning- then why it didn't list that one right away?

Here's another piece I am running in the same environment for deleting files older than 30 days- this also takes time because of the huge volume of files. But, it doesn't take as long (starts deleting as soon as it finds a file to delete) even with the number of files being about 3-4 times the number of folders. Here's the file deletion piece-

```
Get-Item -Path $Delete_APAC -Force -exclude $Keep_this_folder,$Keep_this_folder2|Get-ChildItem -Recurse|Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $regional_limit}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
```

Could anyone suggest improvements to this script to make either script faster if possible?

Comment: using file system actions (going through folders, deleting them etc) remotely (so over a UNC path) is always slow. You should consider using Invoke-Command to run the script "locally" on the remote computer.

Comment: so is there no way to make it fast?

Comment: @alclearner - A method that could help you was just described in the first comment...

Comment: @bluuf also- is there a reason why - oit could be so slow on a remote computer?

Comment: @arco444 I know- I meant- is there a scripting way to do this?

Comment: Scripting way, yes using `Invoke-Command` as mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: @James C. I cannot run it locally because I am not authorized to fire commands on the UNC folder, in the scheduled task I have configured a shared user which has write access on the folder.

Comment: @alclearner - This is because doing file system operations over UNC is always slow (and always been slow since there is way more overhead involved). Simple way to test it : open a UNC folder with a lot of files in Explorer and try to delete it. Now do the same with a copy of the folder but then executed locally.

Comment: If you can't run remote commands you are going to have to accept your script will take many hours. Simply put... UNC paths (and mapped network drives) are slow for any bulk file operations! This is not a PowerShell limitation and there's nothing you can do about this unless you ask Microsoft to rewrite Windows File sharing.

Comment: @bluuf oh! So if I run the above piece from the console using Invoke-Command, it would actually be faster?

Comment: Yes using `Invoke-Command` will be quicker as PowerShell will be interacting with the file system directly rather than using Windows File sharing.

Comment: Could this be done with any other scripting/programming language?